# Merge results of useQuery & useLazyQuery - React Apollo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

While exploring react with @apollo/client, I am using `useQuery` for first time load & `useLazyQuery` for on demand load (after some action, refresh, create etc.) as following:

```
 const { data} = useQuery(GET_POSTS_QUERY);
 const [fetchPosts, { data: fetchedposts}] = useLazyQuery(GET_POSTS_QUERY);
```

I am rendering `data` in my JSX markup, but due to name conflicts I need to get on demand fetched data to other const named `fetchedposts`.

In such case how I will be updating the data on my UI ? My UI is using `data` & not `fetchedposts` !

Is there any way I can merge the 2 states. Or I should go with separate state using `useState` & update the same using these ?

Answer (score 2):

After some more research, got to know that I can utilize `refetch` function returned by useQuery to perform such actions!

So what I am getting here is that in such cases I can avoid useLazyQuery at all & simply go with refetch.

```
const { data, loading, error, refetch} = useQuery(GET_POSTS_QUERY);
.
.
.
<button className="btn btn-raised btn-primary" onClick={() => refetch()}>
  Fetch Posts on Demand
</button>
```

Comment: I just had the same problem and this solves it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JoséDelValle glad it worked for you. As I am progressing with React Learning, I am getting more into it. On other approach can be like ,using separate state using ```useState``` to render on UI & we can always utilize ```useEffect``` to update this state using the results of ```useQuery``` or ```useLazyQuery```.